# How to retrieve the selected ALPN protocol from an asyncio stream?

Tags: python, ssl, python-asyncio, alpn

I am writing a HTTP client in Python.
In order to select the correct HTTP version, I use ALPN.
While there is an easy and documented way to get the selected protocol from a ssl-wrapped socket (`SSLSocket.selected_alpn_protocol()`), I have found no official way to do this for `asyncio` streams.

I am quite new to asyncio, so maybe I have completely misunderstood the concept, but this is still puzzling. Although I have found a way to retrieve the selected protocol, it's too complex to be the official way. Additionally, I have found little to no information on this subject online.

I've found the following:

```
writer.transport._ssl_protocol._sslobj.selected_alpn_protocol()
reader._transport._ssl_protocol._sslpipe.ssl_object.selected_alpn_protocol()
```

These sometimes don't work though, so I have no idea whether this is version specific or I'm just doing something completely wrong.

**Code to reproduce**

```py
import asyncio
import ssl

async def test_alpn():
    ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
    ctx.set_alpn_protocols(["http/1.1", "h2"])
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection('example.org', 443, ssl = ctx, server_hostname = 'example.org')
    return writer.transport._ssl_protocol._sslobj.selected_alpn_protocol()

print(asyncio.run(test_alpn()))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this out way too late, but use the [get_extra_info()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#asyncio.BaseTransport.get_extra_info) function for this.
Extract the SSL object using

```py
writer.transport.get_extra_info("ssl_object")
```

and then call the `selected_alpn_protocol()` function on it.

This is certainly better than messing around with asyncio's internals, as I did originally.